# break loop when condition match

Tags: c, scanf, string-comparison, c-strings

This is a word guessing game. For example, `hello` is given as `h___o` and the user must guess the letters.

I set a condition on my loop but don't know why it is not breaking the `while` loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char word[] = "hello";
int length = strlen(word);
int check;

char spaceLetters[length];
int i, j;
spaceLetters[0] = word[0];
char *dash = "_";

for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
{
  strncat(spaceLetters, dash, 1);
}
int attemptLeft = length;
printf("\n %s\n", spaceLetters);
printf("\t\t\tAttempt Left: %d\n", attemptLeft);
boolean start = T;
int userInput;


while (1)
{
  printf("\n");
  printf("Enter Letter:");
  scanf("%c", &userInput);
```

for loop for checking entered letter is true or not

```
  for (j = 1; j < length;j++)
  {
     if (word[j] == userInput)
     {
        spaceLetters[j] = word[j];
        printf("%s\n", spaceLetters);
        printf("\t\t\tAttempt Left: %d\n", attemptLeft);
        printf("\n");  
                      
     }       
    
  }
```

this is my break loop condition when hello == hello break loop

```
  if(word == spaceLetters){
     break;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You are comparing pointers, not strings. use `strcmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are represented by arrays/pointers.  They need to be compared using string library.  Replace

```
if ( word == spaceLetters )
```

with

```
if ( strcmp ( word, spaceLetters ) == 0 )
```

You'll also need to add `#include <string.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters instead of this call

```
scanf("%c", &userInput);
      ^^^
```

you have to use this call

```
char userInput;
//...
scanf(" %c", &userInput);
      ^^^^
```

Otherwise the call will read also white spaces as the new line character `'\n'` that is stored in the input buffer after pressing the Enter key by the user.

Arrays do not have the comparison operator ==. You have to compare arrays element by element. To compare strings stored in character arrays you should use the standard function `strcmp`

```
  #include <string.h>

  //...

  if( strcmp( word, spaceLetters ) == 0 ){
     break;
  }
```

But before using this function the array `specialLetters` must be declared like

```
char spaceLetters[sizeof( word )] = ""`;
```

That is the array shall contain a string.

Otherwise this for loop in your program invokes undefined behavior.

```
for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
{
  strncat(spaceLetters, dash, 1);
}
```

And it does not make a great sense.

You could just write

```
char dash = '_';
memset( spaceLetters + 1, dash, sizeof( spaceLetters ) - 2 );
```